# how to set up a user field that the only the administrator can access?

Tags: users

I would like to have a STATUS field for certified and uncertified for all users under a certain role preferably, but it could be for all users

how would i go about implementing this?  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Once installed you'll be able to set CRUD permissions on each field's settings form.

Comment: hi, sorry i am new but what is CRUD?  huge thanks!

Comment: this looks just like what i want :)

Comment: @hollyh [Create, read, update and delete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) :)